# How to force drawer to be over header with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I saw other answers regarding this issue but I can't find solution.
I want to show drawer always above app screen and above header. Instead drawer is always bellow header.
What am I doing wrong here:

```
const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: Main, navigationOptions: {
        title: "Main"
      } },
    Home: { screen: Home, navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home"
      } }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Main"
  }
);

const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
      Home: Home, 
      Main: Main
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Main"
    }
  );

  App = createStackNavigator({
    drawer: {
      screen: DrawerNavigation,
    },
    app: {
      screen: AppNavigation
    }
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'drawer',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#a9a9a9'},
          title: 'Welcome!',
          headerTintColor: 'white',
          headerLeft: <Text onPress={() =>
            navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}>Menu</Text>
        })
  });

export default () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <App />
  </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our app is similar to this. You can make the drawer be over the header with `react-navigation` if it is the `<Root />` component of your app (the one you import into `index.js`). For example:

```
export const Root = DrawerNavigator({


 Tabs: {
    screen: Tabs,
    title: 'Tabs'
  },
  STACK1: {
    screen: STACK1,
    title: 'STACK1',
  },
  STACK2: {
    screen: STACK2,
    title: 'STACK2',
  },
});
```

That will give you something like this:

[image]